# How to get focus on TextBox after PostBack and Why Repeater control showing data when TextBox is empty?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a `C# ASP.NET 4` project where I need to have a search box that dynamically searches the content from database's table and shows it in `Repeater Control` everytime I enter alphabet in `TextBox`.

I have done it upto this but the problem is


1) I am losing focus on `TextBox` everytime I enter single alphabet

2) When I erase content in `TextBox`, `Repeater Control` still shows data

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="90%" 
                                ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" 
                                onKeyUp="return serachme()" 
                                AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                                    function serachme() {
                                        __doPostBack('<%=TextBox1.UniqueID %>', "onKeyUp");
                                    }
                                </script>
```

And,

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter mycommand2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select qid,title from globalq where title like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mycommand2.Fill(ds);
    askQ.DataSource = ds;
    askQ.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

I already saw examples of [Set focus in TextBox after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033141/set-focus-in-textbox-after-postback)
and [Set focus in TextBox after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690766/set-focus-on-textbox-after-postback) but did not understood it coz I dont know `JavaScript` that much.

So my Question is
1) How to get focus on `TextBoX` everytime I `__doPostBack`?
2) When I erase content in `TextBox`, Why `Repeater Control` still shows data and how to not show that?

Thanks for your efforts in advance,

Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
con.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter mycommand2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select qid,title from globalq where title like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
mycommand2.Fill(ds); 
askQ.DataSource = ds; 
askQ.DataBind(); 
con.Close(); 

//apply focus back to textbox
TextBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: No, I already tried it. Focus is coming back at the start and also going if I press a single key on keyboard