# Set Focus at end of text in textbox

Tags: asp.net

Hey,
Is it possible with easy options in ASP.NET to set the focus at end of text in a textbox-element ? Without JavaScript ?

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: this link has correct solution

[Set focus to end of text in textbox after postback][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032888/set-focus-to-end-of-text-in-textbox-after-postback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET textboxes render as standard HTML inputs (with type="text") and the only way to achieve what you are asking is through javascript:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('foo');
textbox.focus();
textbox.value = textbox.value;
```

where `foo` is the id of the generated input:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" value="some text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in serve-side:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tmp2", "var t2 =     document.getElementById('foo'); t2.focus();t2.value = t2.value;", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using jquery

```
$('#loginBtn').on('click',function(){
   var val = $('#txtLoginName').val();
   $('#txtLoginName').val('');
   $('#txtLoginName').val(val);
   $('#txtLoginName').focus();
});
```

html code

```
<input type="text" id="txtLoginName" value="test"/>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLpL9uzv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This even works for update panel, i believe all other situations too

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tmp2", "$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtSupplier').focus();var value = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtSupplier').val();$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtSupplier').val('');$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtSupplier').val(value);", true);
```